# How to display this type of view in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

i use `GridLayoutManager` to `RecyclerView` but i require every four row this (provide image) `ViewType`
give me solution

[This type view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnW8Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumning all items have similar views Try This:

```
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(DashboardActivity.this, 2);

 layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {

                if (positions you wish to have a different view) {
                    return 2;
                }
                return 1;

            }
        });
```

Comment: in different view put another layout view

Comment: Check Philipp answer if you have multiple `viewtypes`

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` supports multiple `viewtypes`.

Take a look into this:

[How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //Every 5th view should be different
        return position % 5;
    }

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
```

Comment: i use your given answer in link but problem facing please open this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWddZ.jpg i want to require this type https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnW8Y.jpg

Comment: You need to adopt some functions. You have 2 `viewTypes` with 2 layouts, every 5th viewtype is different. edited my response